# How to reconstruct an image using rgb values of all pixels in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

I am trying to read an image using `imread` then, save the RGB values of all of the pixels in an array. And finally, be able to recreate this image using only the RGB values.

This is the for loop that saves all of the RGB values of each pixel.

```
A=imread('image.jpg');
N=2500; %the image dimensions are 50x50
i=1;
rgbValues = zeros(N, 3);
for x = 1:50
    for y = 1:50
        rgbValues(i,:) = A(x,y,:);
        i=i+1;
    end
end
```

Now, how am I able to recreate this image if I have all of the rgb values saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct way to do this is:

```
ny = 50;
nx = 50;
recreatedImage = zeros(ny,nx,3, 'uint8');
for ind = 1:3    
    recreatedImage(:,:, ind) =  ( reshape(rgbValues(:, ind), nx, ny))';
end
```

As Natan indicated, reshape will work also but you have to do this:

```
recreatedImage=reshape(rgbValues,[ny,nx,3]);
```

Which is, unfortunately, transposed so you will need to work it to get it rotated back up.

You might consider swapping your `x` and `y` values in your for loop so you iterate over all y and then all x values---because this is how MATLAB stores the data and you can change the above code to:

```
for ind = 1:3    
    recreatedImage(:,:, ind) =  ( reshape(rgbValues(:, ind), ny, nx));
end
```

(edit) and then the direct reshape works as well:

```
rgbValuesBacktoShape=reshape(rgbValues,[50,50,3]);
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I ask something more? I save the width and the height of the image, to use instead of (50,50). It works fine, but whenever the image is not a perfect square, then I get this error: `??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` at line: `rgbValues(i,:) = A(x,y,:);`

Comment: Nevermind, re-read your answer, just to see that MATLAB saves (y,x) instead of (x,y).

Comment: @val Yes, it looks like you have your x and y swapped  in `  rgbValues(i,:) = A(x,y,:);` where it should be `  rgbValues(i,:) = A(y,x,:);`

Comment: Using natan's `rgbValues=reshape(A,[],3);` would be very nice, too.